# Radio Button Group in Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, material-ui

I have this project built with react and bootstrap.
I wanted to change to material-ui and it worked well until changing the radio button.

Here is the old one i used (worked pretty well).

```
<label>
    <input type= {that.props.questionType} name={that.props.questionID} value={choice}/>
    {choice}
</label>
```

Here is the material-ui version.

```
<RadioButtonGroup >
    <RadioButton
        value={that.props.questionID}
        label={choice}
    />
</RadioButtonGroup>
```

Here is the map function I use to generate the radio buttons:

```
var iterator = (
  <RadioButtonGroup selectedValue={that.props.questionID}>
    {that.props.questionChoices.map(choice => <RadioButton value={choice} label={choice} /> )}
  </RadioButtonGroup>
);
```

Comment: the old one generates 2 or 3 , because i used JSON files and used map function to display them , the one does too , but it selectes all of them at ounce

Comment: Can you show us the map function you're using?

Comment: Does it generates list of radio buttons? or is that only one?

Comment: it generates a list of radio buttons,, sense i use map function

Comment: var iterator = (
     <RadioButtonGroup selectedValue={that.props.questionID} >
    {that.props.questionChoices.map(choice => <RadioButton value={choice}  label={choice} />
    )}
    </RadioButtonGroup>
    );

Comment: thats the map function

Answer (score 4):

When creating a RadioButtonGroup, you MUST assign **name** property (please refer the [material-ui documentation](https://v0.material-ui.com/#/components/radio-button)).

Also when using a map function you should add a **key** property to each of the returned elements.

Following snippet has those issues addressed:

```
var iterator = ( 
  <RadioButtonGroup 
    name="questionChoices"
    valueSelected={that.props.questionID}
    onChange={that.props.handleChange}
  > 
    {that.props.questionChoices.map(choice => (
       <RadioButton value={choice} label={choice} key={choice}/> 
    )} 
  </RadioButtonGroup> 
)
```